# Getting all Quotes given a specific Tweet?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, twitter

I got this piece of code that goes and gets all statuses given a specific tweet ID. Now what I'd like to find out is who quoted the tweet because quotes do not count as retweets even though they are just retweets with text (derp Twitter?)

If `tweets.statuses` returns a collection of *all* tweets related to the tweet I search for, then it would be reasonable to assume I can use the is_quote_status or whatever that flag is called to determine whether a status related to my tweet is a quote or not.

But now comes the issue because it can only show me 100 tweets at a time. If I want more tweets after that what do I do? From what I can understand `tweets.search_metadata.next_results` will be defined as a query with two IDs; the next ID to look at to get status and then the id you queried originally.

But when I parse the first ID out of the link I receive and use it to queue the system yet again for the next batch of tweets, I get nothing back. Just a search meta data block in a json string.

What am I missing here??

[Twitter API Reference](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets)

Comment: Why not just use the `next_results` value as the query string rather than reconstructing it?

Comment: Here is what I get back from `next_results`: `?max_id=822427279397687295&q=822123183868416001&include_entities=1`. This id here `822123183868416001` is the one I used to make the initial query.